# SSAS CUBE CASE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, ssas-2008

```
Policy Acct_period asl_base_key pricing_terkey  exposure_stkey agency_key Premium_balance
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6609    201201     0             0                0            0            4838.00
6609    201201     0             0                0            6609         4838.00
6609    201201     0             27               0            0             913.00
6609    201201     0             27               0            6609          913.00
6609    201201     0             109              8400         0             155.00
6609    201201     0             109              8400         6609          155.00
```

The table above is the fact table. The dimension tables would be dim policy, dim accounting period, dim asl, dim actuarial pricing, dim exposure state, dim agency.  In Force Premium Balance is the measure. Here is my question:

If I connect to the cube via excel:

If I drop Accounting Period (dim accounting period), Policy number (dim policy) on row labels , In Force Premium Balance (fact table) on values label, it should show as $4838.00

If I drop Accounting Period  (dim accounting period), Policy number (dim policy) , actuarial Pricing code =27(dim actuarial pricing) on row labels , In Force Premium Balance(fact table)  on values label, it should show as $913.00

If I drop Accounting Period  (dim accounting period), Policy number (dim policy) , actuarial Pricing code =109(dim actuarial pricing) , exposure state cd =8400 (dim exposure state) on row labels , In Force Premium Balance (fact table)  on values label, it should show as $155.00

So If I slice the fact table based on the different combinations of dimensions, the measure In Force Premium Balance should pick up the corresponding value from the fact table.

Any help is highly appreciated. Please let me know if I need to provide more information. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: The table design looks ok. It should be easy to set up a cube based on this, ant that would by default behave as you describe. What is your question?